# Change H2 color when mouse hover in DIV

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have changed the background of the DIV when the mouse hovers in that particular DIV. I am using CSS to do this.

```
.home--student:hover {
    background-image: url("blahblah.jpg");
    color:white !important;
}
```

Above is the code I am using for the DIV but the theme I am using has a h2 class that gives the h2 an orange color, the !important does not override it.

Are there any other ways of doing this? Without editing the theme files. I also want the color to go back to orange when the mouse leaves the div so I do not want to change the h2 class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target the `H2` with more specificity than the theme.

Example:

If theme has:

```
h2 { background: orange; }
```

Override it with (considering h2 lives inside `div.someclass` container):

```
div.someclass > h2 { background-color: red; }
```

or if it does not have any parents:

```
body > h2 { ... }
```

or:

```
h2.some-custom-class { ... }
```

Edit: if you want to change the color of H2 when mouse hovers the div:

```
div.home--student:hover > h2 { ... }
```

or if h2 is not direct child of div, then:

```
div.home--student:hover h2 { ... }
```

Comment: I was thinking to do this but I needed it to be trigger when the mouse hovers in the div, it wouldn't really be as good if I just had hover on the h2

Comment: Edited the answer to change h2 color when mouse hovers the div

Comment: Thanks!! I was not aware you could do that

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're going for :

```
.home--student:hover {
    background-image: url("blahblah.jpg");
}

.home--student:hover, .home--student:hover h2 {
    color:white !important;
}
```

`.home--student:hover` targets the `<div>`, and `.home--student:hover h2` targets any `<h2>` inside that `<div>`!

---

#### Note

Are you sure you actually need the `!important`? Unless the CSS you're overriding uses `!important` itself, you don't really need the `!important`.

In that case, just make sure [**the specificity of your CSS**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) is high enough!

Comment: Very helpful explanation and easy way of writing the code, also thank you for the note